# pre-selected values for a dynamic drop-down box with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to pre select values on my edit page in multiple drop down so once user click edit, can see already inserted values. Values are saved as comma separated in MySQL like "1,2,3,4,5"

trying this solution but doesn't work :( , is there is any way that those vales will be pre selected? Please help

```
<select name="w_owning_branches[]" size="10" id="w_owning_branches" multiple="multiple" required>
<option value="" class="dropdown-option">  Select Owning Branch  </option>
<?php do {

$value = $row_branches['branch_id'];
$name = $row_branches['name'];
$selected = '1,2,3,4,5,6';

echo "<option value='$value'".(($selected == '$value') ? " selected='selected'":"").">$name</option>";


} while ($row_branches = mysql_fetch_assoc($branches)); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please search for questions similar to (or exactly the same as) yours prior to posting one because there are plenty of duplicates.

Comment: You might be also interested to read: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Comment: Yes plenty duplicates but cannot locate them, Why vote down ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<select name="w_owning_branches[]" size="10" id="w_owning_branches" multiple="multiple" required>
<option value="" class="dropdown-option">  Select Owning Branch  </option>
<?php do {

$value = $row_branches['branch_id'];
$name = $row_branches['name'];
$selected = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$selected_values = explode(",",$selected);

echo "<option value='$value'".((in_array($value,$selected_values)) ? " selected='selected'":"").">$name</option>";


} while ($row_branches = mysql_fetch_assoc($branches)); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then the selected values are stored in the comma separated string and the numbers are the values the where previously selected.

In that case the answer is simple:

```
<select name="w_owning_branches[]" size="10" id="w_owning_branches" multiple="multiple" required>
<option value="" class="dropdown-option">  Select Owning Branch  </option>
<?php do {

$value = $row_branches['branch_id'];
$name = $row_branches['name'];
$selected = '1,2,3,4,5,6';

echo "<option value='$value'".(in_array($value, explode(",",$selected)) ? " selected='selected'":"").">$name</option>";


} while ($row_branches = mysql_fetch_assoc($branches)); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$selected = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$selectedArr = explode(",", $selected);
echo "<option value='$value'".((in_array($value, $selectedArr))?" SELECTED ":"").">$name</option>";
```